# Typecasting void pointer to unsigned short

Tags: c++

Hi I'm trying to use the code from, http://blog.firetree.net/2006/08/23/nasa-srtm-elevation-data/, with no success, after much chasing around I found where it is failing, but have no idea how to fix it, please help, this has been doing my head in for about 6 hours.
This is the line that fails. data is a void pointer to a memory mapped file.

```
unsigned short datum=((unsigned short*)data)[i];
```

I'm on OpenSuse using the gcc compiler. I'm on a 64bit system.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually you are not casting data to `unsigned short` but to `unsigned short*`. The `unsigned short` is obtained by indexing that.

Comment: besides needing a more accurate error description: what is `i` and how long is the accessible memory for `data`

Comment: Silently, I run it and get no output from the function that calls it. Using the debugger an break points it gets to this point then I presume crashes as it jumps out of the function and gives no response.

Comment: @wookie1: If it jumps out of the function, then it hasn't crashed.

Comment: i is an unsigned int obtained by adding the column the data is expected to be in to the row*num of columns. I'm sorry i don't know what you mean by "how long is the accessible memory for data". Or how to find this out.

Comment: @wookie1: Fundamentally, there isn't enough information here to be able to answer your question.  You should consider creating a 10-line [minimal test case](http://sscce.org) that is capable of recreating the problem, and then posting that.

Answer (score 2):

I think maybe this is caused by the memory alignment.
in some platform pointer value can't be cast to some types.

for example, a platform needs int* should be aligned with 4, so 0x12345 can be void* or char*, but if you assigned it to int*, crash happened.

for your situation,
you can cast the void pointer to unsigned char* first, then convert 2 unsigned chars to unsigned short:

```
unsigned char a =((unsigned char*)data)[i];
unsigned char b =((unsigned char*)data)[i+1]; 
if (platform_is_little_endian()) {
    unsigned short datatum = (b << sizeof(unsigned char)) | a;
}
else {
    // platform is big endian
    unsigned short datatum = (a << sizeof(unsigned char)) | b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying it crashes at that point, then I would imagine you were reading outside of the array. But storing a pointer to an unsigned short as an unsigned short is interesting to say the least, does that even compile?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by a combination of Donald Tangs method and the realization that the program was reading outside the array. For other potential users the problem occurs when finding the value of num_rows num_cols as the authors square root function doesn't square root.